# Better way than ''.html_safe when building html string in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html-safe

Typical pattern:

```
out = ''.html_safe # or ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new
out << content_tag(...) if foo
out << 'hello, 1 < 2' # will be escaped properly
out << content_tag(...) if bar

out
```

This works fine. Is there a nicer / shorter / better way than this, in particular calling `''.html_safe`?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't upvote this, as I don't think it's really the answer you're looking for.  But I figured I'd share some thoughts for consideration anyway.

This is actually probably harder to read, but I would be interested in seeing the results of a benchmark vs. the implementation used in your question.

```
out = "#{content_tag(...) if foo}" <<
      "hello, 1 < 2" <<
      "#{content_tag(...) if bar}"
out.html_safe
```

Also, I'm not familiar with the internals of how `html_safe` to know whether there's a difference in setting it as so initially vs. prior to returning.  I'm guessing initial setting of `html_safe` would be faster since you're duplicating a zero-length string instead of a potentially long string, but for the sake of argument:

```
out = '' # or ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new
out << content_tag(...) if foo
out << 'hello, 1 < 2' # will be escaped properly
out << content_tag(...) if bar
out.html_safe
```

With that in mind, I would consider modifying my original code from above to even take it a step further:

```
"#{content_tag(...) if foo}".html_safe <<
"hello, 1 < 2" <<
"#{content_tag(...) if bar}"
```

Again, not very readable, but thought I'd throw it out there as food for thought.

Comment: Your first two examples will not escape the `<`. You still have an `html_safe` in your last one, so nothing was gained...

Comment: I'm confused...all 3 of them have calls to `html_safe`.  Maybe I misunderstood your original question.  What are you trying to accomplish (or avoid)?

Comment: `"".html_safe + "<" # => "&lt;"` while `"<".html_safe # => "<"`